# jQuery: Target ONLY Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, conditional-statements

I'm using this bit of jQuery code to target Safari:

```
if ($.browser.safari) {
    $('#div1').css({'margin-top': '-22px'});
    $('#div2').css({'margin-top': '-17px'});
}
```

Oddly, it also targets Chrome (at least Mac version). What jQuery code can I use that would ignore Chrome and target only Safari?

I would be grateful for expert advice.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. I have something displayed perfectly well in Chrome and all messed up in Safari.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

(Edit so that Chrome must not be in the user agent):

(Edit2 because Chrome for iOS has "CriOS" instead of "Chrome" in its user agent):

```
if (
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && 
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1 && 
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('CriOS/') == -1
)  { 
   //i.e. apply safari class via jquery
}
```

P.S. You should consider using [Feature Detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection) to change your website according to what the current browser can do instead of checking for user agents, which you have to update regulary.

Comment: Nope, it targets Chrome, too. Would appreciate more ideas from you.

Comment: The userAgent of Chrom is _Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.2.149.27 Safari/525.13_, the userAgent of Safari is _Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8; de-at) AppleWebKit/533.21.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.5 Safari/533.21.1_. Perhaps you should do this: `if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1)`

Comment: PERFECT. This last suggestion does exactly what I need: targets Safari and de-targets Chrome. Thank you, Wulf.

Comment: Its not validating in Chrome on iPhone. Giving success. Any solution to that?

Comment: Chrome for iOS has "CriOS/" in the name. So just validate, that "CriOS/" also doesn't exist in the UserAgent.

Anyway, the question/comment is from 2011. Nowadays you show use feature detection instead of targetting specific user agents :)

Answer (score 4):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') && !navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome')) {
    // Yep, it's Safari =)
}else {
    // Nope, it's another browser =(
}
```

Comment: Alas, that one also Safari / Chrome. What I need is the code that would only target Safari. Any suggestions?

Comment: I edited it, probably when you were typing :). Try it again ;)!

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful and confirms what I learned a few seconds ago from Wulf. Voted up.

Answer (score 1):

Feature detection is preferred over browser sniffing, but I did find this solution on SO:

[Detect Safari using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899783/detect-safari-using-jquery/6372119#6372119)

Comment: Linking to an article without providing the solution in your own answer is discouraged.

Comment: @Seano Can you link me to relevant guideline?

Comment: Ah, you linked to an SO article. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.browser.safari = ( $.browser.safari && /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) ) ? false : true;
```

I like this a little better because you're setting the jQuery property properly, and can then use it elsewhere without constantly checking on the userAgent.

Answer (score 0):

This Works Fine to know whether browser is Safari.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') !=-1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1)
{
    alert('its safari');
}else{
    alert('its not safari');
}
```