# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jjavascript to resize iframes:

```
 $(function () {

            var iFrames = $('iframe');

            function iResize() {

                for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                    iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
                }
            }

            if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) {

                iFrames.load(function () {
                    setTimeout(iResize, 0);
                });

                for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                    var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
                    iFrames[i].src = '';
                    iFrames[i].src = iSource;
                }

            } else {
                iFrames.load(function () {
                    this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
                });
            }

        });
```

In chrome, it has trouble here:

```
 if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) {
```

Is there any reason why I get this error? I am using the latest JQuery?

Thanks

Comment: `$.browser` is gone. Why do you need to detect those browsers?

Comment: fyi http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ - you should no longer be using the jQuery browser api and should use jquery.support instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is jQuery $.browser Deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638247/is-jquery-browser-deprecated) and [tons of others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[jquery]+%22%24.browser%22).

Answer (score 14):

You are probably using jQuery 1.9 or above, in which case [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) was officially removed after being deprecated since 1.3.

You can use [jQuery migrate](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/31/jquery-migrate-1-1-0-released/) which will patch it, but it's better to move to a feature specific approach instead of browser specific approach. [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) is great for this.

Answer (score 3):

jquery recommends against `$.browser`... use `$.support` instead..

if `$.browser.safari` (or opera or whatever your trying to access) doesn't exist it throws an error. check if its `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this issue today with a client who upgraded without telling me.

The quick fix I issued (without using Modernizr which is probably a better way)

On the scrollTo.js file go to line 85 and make it this:

```
        var is_safari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;

        return is_safari || doc.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking the userAgent string:

> Chrome has both 'Chrome' and 'Safari' inside userAgent string. Safari
>   has only 'Safari'.

[Detect Safari using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899783/detect-safari-using-jquery)