# On page anchor not working

Tags: html, css, anchor

The code *should* be exactly the same on the staging server and it works, but on our live site:

http://www.dreambox.com/white-papers/educators-data-decision-making

If you click on the white paper on the right side bar, it doesn't work, BUT does work if you open in new windows. What am I missing? I am baffled.

Comment: With Chrome on Mac OS X, looks like a Javascript TypeError with message `Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined` is swallowed by jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js when I click on the img link.

Comment: There's a line in that script `return d.browser.safari || e.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ? e.body : e.documentElement` and `d.browser` is always undefined.

Comment: Looks like jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2 may be incompatible with jquery-1.9.1. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011729/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-safari-of-undefined

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading jquery.scrollTo to latest version (currently 1.4.6).

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/releases

Same thing for webshim-polyfiller.

https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/releases

Might want to check all other jquery plugins too.

Comment: The live and staging should be clones of each other and the on page anchor works just fine on the staging server here: http://www-cloud.dreambox.com/white-papers/intelligent-adaptive-learning-an-essential-element-of-21st-century-teaching-and-learning#download_paper

Comment: You're page is loading 2 different versions of `jquery.min.js` there - one is 1.8.3 and the other is 1.9.1. The jquery plugins you're using are compatible with 1.8.3, but not 1.9.1. Note that you're only loading 1.9.1 in your live environment, thus the problem.

Comment: @pood - Looks like your live environment has been fixed by upgrading your jquery plugins. If this answer helped you, please 'accept' it as the correct one. Thanks.