# Jquery change input file multiple to single

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if(//safari 5.1.7){
  //use jquery change to single file only

}

<input type='file' name="image[]"  multiple="multiple"/>
```

I have an input file can upload multiple files, but I need a use jquery change to single if safari 5.1.7

because Safari 5.1.7 have bug when I try to upload multiple files, single file is ok

Comment: how is that bug? there is a deprecated feature called `$.browser` may help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899783/detect-safari-using-jquery-browser-detection

Comment: i'm not asking detect safari, i'm asking how to change input file from multiple to single

Comment: @BenWong it's simply by removing the `multiple` attribute, the default is single.

Comment: do I need to change 'image[]' to 'image'? please put it in answer so I can close this question

Comment: `$('input[type="file"]').prop("multiple", false)`? Is that what you're asking? But who uses that obsolete Safari version nowadays?