# Does 100vh not work in safari in windows?

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser

The front page of a website I have been building to learn some web development works well in all browsers I have tested it on (windows) except safari. I have a html step such that i have sections styled to be 100vw and 100vh. On safari they appear to have a height of 0;

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="main">
            <section id="slide-one" class="slide"></section>
            <section id="slide-two" class="slide"></section>
.
.
.
```

And a summary of the css:

```
.slide {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
    //alert('Its Safari');
    $('.main').css('min-height', '650px');
}
```

Although 100vh css property working on Mac default safari browser. But does not work properly in Safari in Windows.

Reference Link
[Detect Safari using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899783/detect-safari-using-jquery)

Comment: iphone safari crops web pages too:/

Answer (score 2):

The `-webkit-height` overrules the normal height, and because the value is `100%` it will be as high as the `.main`. This only occurs in Safari (and maybe some other WebKitbrowsers), since Chrome doesn't recognise `-webkit-height`.

Comment: thanks for the fast response. Unfortunately this didn't make a difference though. Here is the website for your reference: www.teamthie.com

Comment: @DB1500 I can't test Safari, unfortunately. The only thing I can think of is the support for viewport units, but they're fine in Safari since 6.1, according to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: @DB1500 Great the website is actually up and running and can be checked! So many times devs/users post links to the website they currently work on and once the bug/error/question is answered/done the link is dead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Safari 5.1.7 is the last version of Safari developed for Windows. It came out before 2012 therefore it doesn't support most of new CSS3 properties.